# How to test if mail have been send using mockito junit5

Tags: java, mockito, junit5

I have a REST API application for looking changes in text files. I have a @Async metod for looking changes and sending email for "subscribers". (I have a list of people who can follow changes in file). If some changes in file happen they should get email with information that something has been changed.

I need to test this method. Most important in test Is to know if mail have been send.
I have no idea how I can try to test it.

```
@Async
@Transactional
@EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
public void fileListener() throws IOException, InterruptedException, WrongIdException, NoEntityException {
    LOGGER.info("chodzi");
    WatchService watchService
            = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();

    Path path = Paths.get(AppConstants.FOLDER_TO_WATCH_URL);

    path.register(watchService, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_MODIFY);

    WatchKey key;

    while ((key = watchService.take()) != null) {

        for (WatchEvent<?> event : key.pollEvents()) {
            String fileName = event.context().toString();
            LOGGER.info("Zaszla zmiana w jakims pliku");

            Listener listener = listenerManagementService.findListenerByFileName(fileName);;
            // zaczynamy od sprawdzenia czy taki listener jest w bazie dancyh
            if (listener != null) {
                LOGGER.info("Plik jest w bazie danych");

                // kolejno sprawdzamy czy ktos ten plik subskrybuje
                if (!listener.getUsers().isEmpty()) {
                    LOGGER.info("Plik jest subskrybowany");

                    // bierzemy listenera z bazy danych aby otrzymac wielkosc pliku w bajtach przed modyfikacja
                    long fileSizeBeforeModified = listener.getFileSize();

                    // otrzymujemy akutalna wielkosc pliku w bajtach po zmianie
                    long size = Files.size(Path.of(listener.getFilePath()));

                    // aktualizujemy ilosc bajtow dla listenera w bazie danych
                    listener.setFileSize(size);
                    listenerManagementService.edit(listener);

                    // bierzemy liste maili ktora subskrybuje dany plik
                    List<String> emails = listener.getUsers().stream()
                            .map(User::getEmail)
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());

                    //sprawdzamy czy plik nie jest za duzy
                    if (checkIfSizeIsNotToBig(size)) {
                        LOGGER.info("Mail jest wysylany (aktualizacja)");

                        // tworzymy wiadomosc do wyslania w mailu
                        byte[] newContent = getNewContent(listener.getFilePath(), (int) fileSizeBeforeModified, (int) size);
                        String newContentForEmail = getNewContentForEmail(newContent);
                        String emailContentForSend = getEmailContentForSend(newContentForEmail, fileName);

                        // dla kazdego subskrybenta wysylamy mail
                        sendMailToSubscribers(emails, emailContentForSend);

                    } else {
                        LOGGER.info("Mail jest wysylany (za duzo nowej tresci)");
                        // jesli za duzo tesktu zostalo dopisane to subskrybenci dostana tylko info o nadpisaniu
                        sendMailToSubscribers(emails, "Twoj plik zostal nadpisany, ale zawartosc jest za duza" +
                                " zeby otrzymac ja mailem");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        key.reset();
    }
}

// Metoda zwraca ostateczna tresc wiadomosci dla subskrybenta
private String getEmailContentForSend(String updatedContent, String fileName) {
    Date date = new Date();
    String dateToSend = formatter.format(date);
    return "Dnia: " + dateToSend + " zmieniono plik: " + fileName + ", dopisano do niego: " + updatedContent;
}

// Metoda ktora czyta update w pliku na podstawie zmienionej wielkosci
private byte[] getNewContent(String filePath, int position, int size) throws IOException {
    RandomAccessFile file = new RandomAccessFile(filePath, "r");
    file.seek(position);
    byte[] bytes = new byte[size];
    file.read(bytes);
    file.close();
    return bytes;
}

// metoda konwertuje bajty na stringa
private String getNewContentForEmail(byte[] bytes) {
    return new String(bytes);
}

// metoda dostarcza listener, dzieki temu mozemy sie odwolac do filepatha i emaili
private Listener getListener(String fileName) {
    return listenerManagementService.findListenerByFileName(fileName);
}

// metoda ktora wysyla maile - dla jednej zmiany - 1 watek
public void sendMailToSubscribers(List<String> emails, String content) {
    mailService.sendSimpleEmail(emails, content);
}

// sprawdza czy nadpisanego tesktu nie jest za duzo aby go wczytac i wyslac mailem
private boolean checkIfSizeIsNotToBig(long size) {
    return size < 1500;
}
```

Comment: By the way don't look at comments, they are in my national language, I forgot to delete them

Comment: You inject a mock `mailService` component, and verify that `sendSimpleEmail` has been called on it with the expected parameters.